# Exponential function application

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I am given the half life of a certain object is $1599$ years and the amount after $10,000$ years is $0.5\ \text{grams}$. How do I find initial quantity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the model be: $A(t) = Pe^{rt}$, then you have: $A(1599) = \dfrac{P}{2}, A(10,000) = 0.5$. Thus: $\dfrac{P}{2} = Pe^{1599r} \implies r = -\dfrac{\ln 2}{1599} \approx -0.00043$. Thus $A(t) = Pe^{-0.00043t}$. Next $0.5 = Pe^{10,000(-0.00043)} = Pe^{-4.3}\implies P = 0.5e^{4.3}\approx 36.85$ units.

Comment: yes I got it from here, thank you so much!

Comment: question when setting equal to $P/2$ don't the $P$'s cancel out

Comment: Yes, they cancel out but you still solve for $r$ first and then come back solve for $P using the second data.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more, sorry I am not seeing it

Comment: when I do that, I get $r$ to be negative and very small

Comment: Yes, it should be because it is decaying and the quantity must decrease. Hence $r$ must be negative.

Comment: I keep getting the wrong answer though, could you help out a bit more

Comment: but the answer of the initial quantity is $38.16$ grams

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake on the decimal. It should be $4.3$. It's good now. Check it again. Its thirty point some thing for sure.